# Appending and Mapping of two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, append, mapping

I have two tables in the database, I want to merge and map the table 2

[image]

into table 1

[image]

by writing SQL query.

I don't know whether to apply joins or what? and then how to append the data.
note: Customer id is the common key in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

A simple INNER JOIN would solve your problem --

```
SELECT T1.[Branch Code]
    ,T1.[CustomerID]
    ,T2.[Customer Name]
    ,T1.[Advised Amount]
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 
ON T1.CustomerID = T2.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Inner join..... U can write column name in place of *

```
Select * from Table1 as a
    inner join Table2 as b on a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
```